# Wifi USB adapter hard blocked

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using an older HP laptop which has a touch pad controller for sound and wifi. After a while the touch pad started spazzing out and doing things on its own (turning wifi on and off randomly and lowering or raising the sound volume), so i opened the laptop and unplugged the touch pad. Now I am trying to get a wifi USB adapter to work, and it shows it in the network settings but it doesn't work. Doing `rfkill list all` shows that it is hard blocked. Is it possible that the wifi button on the pad was left disabled after the unplugging and that its blocking my adapter?
Output of rfkill list:

`0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of ` rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter is blocked by `rfkill`

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp.conf <<< "blacklist hp_wmi"
```

and reboot.

You can also try to reset BIOS to defaults. It helps on some cases to reset hard block.

Comment: rfkill list now only shows:
        0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: Then you may need to find a hardware switch, or check BIOS settings, or reset BIOS to defaults.

Comment: Resetting BIOS to defaults seems to have done the trick. Thank you